# SF TV show about a war between humans and aliens?

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching this TV show in the early- or mid-nineties (I think) that was about a war between humans and a mysterious alien race. At least some of the episodes focused on learning new things about the aliens. Specifics that I recall:

- The aliens were called "chigs" or "chiggers" or something like that. [I'm not really certain on this bit, to be honest, but I do recall there was some kind of slang term the characters used for the aliens that always made me think of some kind of insect.]
- The show focused on a particular group of human soldiers/pilots (they seemed to do as much space combat as ground combat, as I recall).
- The show featured a brand new element, although I forget what it was called, and there was even an updated periodic table that included it. Pretty much all of the aliens' technology was based on this element and its unique properties.

It was a pretty dark show (both in theme and in actual lighting), and they seemed to go out of their way to never give the audience a good view of the aliens (probably trying to increase the mysteriousness of them); in fact, I seem to recall one episode in particular where they had captured the dead body of one of the aliens, and yet they still refused to give the audience a clear look at this creature.

I believe it was short-lived, canceled after just 1 or 2 seasons (possibly mid-season, I seem to recall story arcs remaining unresolved). I remember really enjoying the show, and would love to look it up again and re-watch it, but not remembering the title makes that a bit awkward...

If you need more detail, please ask -- I remember bits and pieces of several of the episodes, and with some prompts I should be able to provide additional details.

Comment: It was cancelled after one season, but the last episode was written as a typical cliffhanger story which would have been resolved at the start of the next season, if it had been renewed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sounds like [*Space: Above and Beyond*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%3a_Above_and_Beyond) (one full season, 1995-96):

> Set in the years 2063–2064, the show focuses on the "Wildcards",
>   members of the United States Marine Corps Space Aviator Cavalry, 58th
>   Squadron. They are stationed on the space carrier USS Saratoga, and
>   act as infantry and pilots of SA-43 Endo/Exo-Atmospheric Attack Jet
>   ("Hammerhead") fighters.

You also correctly remembered the nickname humans gave the aliens: ["Chigs"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chigs) (it's how I managed to find it).

Comment: dang, just beat me by 10 seconds.

Comment: "Chigs" is like so totally "S:aab".  (It was nicknamed "Melrose Space" by some who didn't like it)

Comment: Yes! That is exactly it! As soon as I read "Saratoga" I remembered the carrier, and then "Hammerhead" sealed the deal for me that this is indeed the show I was trying to remember! Thank you!

Comment: Check out this boot camp scene featuring R. Lee Ermey - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5b1q-IlxGrk Sadly, this Full Metal Jacket rehash was about the only good thing about a series that looked promising at first.

Comment: Great show.  One of many Fox cancelled before it's time (like Firefly).

Comment: @jfrankcarr: Gunny is pure awesome.